# Python process vs Jupyter notebook acces to GPU memory

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, nvidia

I made a very interesting observation while trying to tune my recommendation engine on a Tesla K80 housed on Google Cloud Platform. Unfortunately I have been unsuccessful at finding any literature which might point me in the right direction. Here is my predicament ...

I run the same code for fitting a fully connected model using a python script and a jupyter notebook. What is surprising is that with the same hyper-parameters (batch size etc.), the code runs faster using the jupyter notebook kernel and uses more memory on the GPU than when I fit the model using a python code invoked from the shell.

Since, I want my code to run in the least possible time and jupyter often ends up closing the connection when unattended due to web socket time-out, is there any way I can increase the amount of memory a python process can use on the GPU ? Open to any alternating way of making this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its more likely that you have multiple python installations, with different software versions that explain the issue.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, I am pretty sure that both run on the same version of python. The only install of python is the one that is bundled with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Hence, I would expect them to behave in a similar fashion.